# Checking if numbers are approximately equal in Karate

Tags: karate

I'm working with Karate, and I need to compare two numbers for approximate equality. Is there a built-in function or a recommended approach in Karate to check if two numbers are approximately equal within a certain tolerance?

For example, in other programming languages, there might be a function like assertAlmostEqual or a way to specify a delta for equality checks. Does Karate have a similar feature, or is there a standard practice for handling approximate equality in numeric comparisons?

Comment: I know I can use Java or Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a re-usable function:

```
* def isAlmostEqual = (actual, expected) => Math.abs(actual - expected) < 0.1
* assert isAlmostEqual(1.0, 1.05)
```

Comment: yes, I know it. but assertions is not like match. Assertion does not print the same information (in case of error) printed by the keyword match

Comment: @RachidG perhaps you can contribute code to karate to make it better